# Leaflet how to convert a L.CRS.SIMPLE coordinate to a normal L.CRS.Earth one

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, system, coordinate

I have a leaflet map set with a CRS of L.CRS.SIMPLE and several Markers.
The tiles are custom tiles pulled from my server (the usual /zoom/x/y.png) format.

I'm building a mobile app with Android using the same tiles and so using Google Map the coordinate system is different but I would like to reuse all my Markers coordinate.

Is there a way to convert the marker's simple coordinate to a coordinate that can be used on the google map coordinate system ?

More info:
The map is a fictional game map that I have tiled myself from a hung PNG file.
I had set my Leaflet MAP CRS like this:

```
crs: L.Util.extend({}, L.CRS, {
                code: "simple",
                projection: L.Projection.LonLat,
                transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, -1, 0)
            }),
```

The WebApp let users add their own Markers on it, I had saved all the Marker lat/lng using what the leaflet map was giving.

I'm now trying to build a native Android app using the exact same tiles which works fine however I do not know how to put all the Marker on it since Google Map use the normal earth lat/lng coords.

Is it even possible to covert from L.CRS.SIMPLE to whatever Google Map uses ?

Comment: I suspect there's a [XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How do your maps look like? Are the maps related to the earth, or are they fictional? Are you just trying to use an equivalent of `L.CRS.Simple` in the Android GMaps libraries?

Comment: @IvanSanchez It is a fictional (game) map that I have tiled my self. I'm not trying to use L.CRS.Simple on the Android Google Map (I don't think you can change CRS) I'm just trying to reuse my Marker that were initially created using the L.CRS.Simple on the Android Google Map (My webap that uses leaflet allow user to set custom marker that are saved in my DB and.. I had save all the Markers using the L.CRS.Simple coords) –